# Does something like CHESS exist for Java?

Tags: java, concurrency, race-condition

> CHESS is a tool for finding and reproducing Heisenbugs in concurrent
>   programs. CHESS repeatedly runs a concurrent test ensuring that every
>   run takes a different interleaving. If an interleaving results in an
>   error, CHESS can reproduce the interleaving for improved debugging. [[Source]](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/chess/default.aspx)

Does a tool like this exist for Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concurrent code analyzer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090691/concurrent-code-analyzer)

Comment: Not duplicate, that question is about whether a proposed static code analysis method would work. I ask for a tool like CHESS, which will repeatedly execute Java code and ensure that all possible thread interleaving are exercised. I am not saying that the other questions is not interesting, though.

Answer (score 4):

Haven't used in personally, but the book *Clean Code* by Robert C. Martin describes a tool from IBM called ConTest that is supposed to aid concurrent testing similarly:

[ConTest - A Tool for Testing Multi-threaded Java Applications](http://www.haifa.ibm.com/projects/verification/contest/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

The only tool I'm aware of that's somewhat like what you're describing is an academic project called RoadRunner, which is described in this paper:

[The ROADRUNNER Dynamic Analysis Framework for Concurrent Programs](http://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~cormac/papers/paste10.pdf)

And available for download here:

[The RoadRunner Dynamic Analysis Framework](http://www.cs.williams.edu/~freund/rr/)

Again, I don't think that's exactly what you're looking for, but I'm not aware of anything closer. I'll be interested to see if anyone comes up with an exact analogue.